# House (old around 1965) wiring and line voltage differences

Tags: electrical

I have a problem with my Comcast cable connecting to the house. It is melting and partially burned out.  The burn is on the pole side coming to the house and not the house side.  There is an earthing connection secure between them.  I have these readings in my house outlets. 
hot - ground = 16v, 
hot - neutral = 122v, 
neutral - ground = 5v.
Is this something to be concerned about or to be taken care of?

Comment: This sounds like another grounding problem, possibly caused by a neighbor.  We [had this come up](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/181882/how-did-my-ground-and-neutral-become-energized-by-a-short-in-the-buried-main-lin/181890#181890) last week or so.

Comment: Can you post the voltage readings for outlets on *both legs* of the supply? This has the smell of trouble with the service neutral...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to get this fixed. Comcast cables on the poles should not be burning. You need to report this to the power company and also to the cable company. Tell them are are cables burning on the pole. It is their responsibility to fix that. Your hot to ground reading should be 122V, same as your hot to neutral. Have the power company also check the grounding at your meter. They might tell you that you need an electrician.